# Locking down Sitecore rendering caching

Tags: security, caching

Sitecore has some lovely granular security permissions that can help us stop users doing things which can break the site, however one thing I can't obviously see is how to limit access to the caching panel on the control properties when adding components to pages.

[image]

It's not the end of the world but can access to this be controlled by roles at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove access to `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters/Caching`

1. Navigate to the item
2. Open `Security` tab
3. Click on `Assign` button
4. In the dialog which will appear select user or group (preferably) from whom you would like to hide the section
5. Remove the inheritance for the item and its descendats